# Declare Table Name for a model in EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

In EF Core how do you declare the name of the table it will create. Currently when you use "Add-Migration" it uses the name of the model when it create the table. Is there anyway to change that instead of using the name of my model.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to add a [TableAttrbiute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to your entity classes.  Eg

```
[Table(Name = "customer_orders")]
public class CustomerOrder
{
    // ...
}
```

This can also be done in DbContext.OnModelCreating using the Fluent API.

Comment: How come its not resolving "Table", note does this work on .net core?

Comment: I think I found the answer, I only use Table without name   [Table("customer_orders")]